# can I pass a list in sql query to search

Tags: mysql, hql

I want a sql query which serves to return a list of values of the inputted and get a returned list.
suppoze I have two fields in a table.
values [1-a,2-b,3-c,4-d], I pass in [a,c] how do I get [1,3]?

Comment: Are those column names? Column values? What is the structure of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the queries list and store the results in a results list. I dont think you can query a list of values at a time. One more approach is you can use 'where value = a or value = c'.

Comment: Ok, I go this, but I want to sort the resultant list with order by asc/desc. how do I do that now?

Comment: that's very easy. you can use any kind of sorting on that list. which programming language you use?

Comment: @sans : I have done that using programing language but want to use sql quey. I am using groovy language sort{it.field}

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where columname1 in ('a','c');
```

Comment: columname1 in ('a','c'); here  ('a','c') is a list?

Comment: i suppose a and c are values in one of the columns of your table. if so then give the name of that column. the query above is saying fetch me all the records in the table whose column(specified by columname) has values in ( value1, value2,.. , value n)

Comment: I dont want t specify values in code, I want it to be based on whatever value is passed

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your desired output-

```
select group_concat(col2) where col1 in ('a','c')
```